# Web Page Setup on Apache Server via Flask Using Raspberry Pi

Tags: python, apache, flask, http-post, wsgi

I have been struggling with web development using Flask. I am developing a remote controlled pet feeder. I want to create a website to stream video from the camera on Pi and dispense food with the button on this website.

- Project folder: `/var/www/PetFeeder`
- Python script: `/var/www/PetFeeder/PetFeeder.py`

*My python script calls other scripts (for camera etc.) which are again located under the folder 'PetFeeder'. When I run this script through Terminal it starts publishing my HTML and buttons etc. works just fine. However it is only on the IP address of the Pi on port `:5000`. No access from outside of the local network.

- Html file for my web page: `/var/www/PetFeeder/templates/index.html`
- WSGI file: `/var/www/PetFeeder/PetFeeder.wsgi`
- Conf. file: `/etc/apache2/sites-available/my.PetFeeder.conf`
- 127.0.0.1 in the /etc/hosts was already in the file written 'localhost' in front of it. So, I just changed it to my.PetFeeder.
- Content of `/var/www/PetFeeder/PetFeeder.wsgi`:

  ```
  import sys
  sys.path.append('/var/www/PetFeeder')
  from PetFeeder import app as application
  ```
- Content of /etc/apache2/sites-available/my.PetFeeder.conf:

  ```
  <virtualhost *:80>
        ServerName my.PetFeeder
        WSGIDaemonProcess PetFeeder user=www-data group=www-data threads=5 home=/var/www/PetFeeder/
        WSGIScriptAlias / /var/www/PetFeeder/PetFeeder.wsgi
        <directory /var/www/PetFeeder>
            WSGIProcessGroup PetFeeder
            WSGIApplicationGroup %{GLOBAL}
            WSGIScriptReloading On
            Order deny,allow
            Allow from all
        </directory>
  </virtualhost>
  ```

*a2ensite my.PetFeeder returns 'Site .. already enabled'

*apache2 restart successfully returns [ok] Restarting apache2 ..

*Also when I go to the IP_of_Raspberry on my web browser I see the 'It Works!' main page of Apache.

However, I cannot reach the PetFeeder page from any possible addresses. I tried following, and don't know if there are any others. I would be more than happy if someone can help. Thank you...

- `http://my.PetFeeder/`
- `IP_of_RaspberryPi/my.PetFeeder`
- `IP_of_RaspberryPi:80`

Comment: Try this command locally on your PI:  curl localhost/ -H "Host: my.PetFeeder"

Comment: @Joshua I did on terminal. Some kind of html code returned on the terminal. What does it mean?

Comment: That acts like a web browser on the terminal, requesting a page on that URL. If you examine the HTML, was it your PetFeeder app?

Comment: @Joshua No, actually it was the Apache main page. Do you have any idea why the Apache page is running instead of my web page?

Comment: Maybe you have a default virtualhost defined that is overriding your config? Check /etc/apache2/sites-enabled and delete all links there except your petfeeder.